# Overflow error in Python program

Tags: python

Please help me to understand why this code doesn't work. I know there is something very stupid wrong. This should be an implementation of the fourth order Runge kutta algorithm to solve Lorentz system of equations. I can't use any function because is an assignment.The errors are:

> Warning (from warnings module): File
>   "/Users/giuseppenegro/Desktop/loretnz.py", line 21 fy =x*ro-y-x*z
>   RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
>
> Warning (from warnings module): File
>   "/Users/giuseppenegro/Desktop/loretnz.py", line 22 fz =x*y-beta*z
>   RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
>
> Warning (from warnings module): File
>   "/Users/giuseppenegro/Desktop/loretnz.py", line 22 fz =x*y-beta*z
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
>
> Warning (from warnings module): File
>   "/Users/giuseppenegro/Desktop/loretnz.py", line 32
>   r+=(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6 RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in
>   add

```
from numpy import array,arange,zeros
from pylab import plot,xlim,show
ro=28
beta=8/3
sigma=10
a=0
b=50
r=array([0.0,1.0,0.0],float)

N=10
h=(b-a)/N
tpoints=arange(a,b,h)
xpoints=[]
ypoints=[]
zpoints=[]
def f(r,t):
     x=r[0]
     y=r[1]
     z=r[2]
     fx =sigma*(y-x)
     fy =x*ro-y-x*z
     fz =x*y-beta*z
     return array([fx,fy,fz],float)
for t in tpoints:
    xpoints.append(r[0])
    ypoints.append(r[1])
    zpoints.append(r[2])
    k1=h*f(r,t)
    k2=h*f(r+0.5*k1,0.5*h+t)
    k3=h*f(r+0.5*k2+0.5,0.5*h+t)
    k4=h*f(r+k3,t+h)
    r+=(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
```

Comment: Could you explain, what you mean by "It does not work"?

Comment: It give me the error "overflow encountered in double_scalars"

Comment: Where does it give you this error?

Comment: Post the full error and format you're code so that it's readable (read PEP8). Space the tokens at least. As it stands, your code is a pain to read, and thus is less likely to receive an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Runge-Kutta methods need to advance in small steps, `5` is not a small step.  Try setting N to `1000.0` instead (the decimal is to make sure that `(b-a)/N != 0`).